# Serving golang scripts from nginx

Tags: nginx, go

I want to write a web application with go language.

When in run:

```
go run myscript.go
```

It works fine, i have worked with go "net/http" module
Here is what i've done in my go script:

```
http.ListenAndServe(":8081", nil)
```

I want now to work with nginx. I have read i should put nginx in proxy mode. That means when nginx receive an http request on 80 http port, it will proxy it do 8081 port.

How can i automatically lanuch and relaunch "go run" process ?

Comment: Are you want, that the nginx should launch and relaunch `go run` or what?

Comment: Yes if it is possible i would like the nginx launch and relaunch the go run command

Comment: nginx is a reverse proxy server it's not a supervisor or anything like  that, it does one thing and does it well.

Comment: That is not the way things work. Nginx expects you to give it a address and port to forward to. You should look at systemd for doing automatic launching of your go process. Nginx should be concerned about proxying the request and not process management

Comment: It is strange, but here it is - https://www.nginx.com/products/nginx-unit/.

Answer (score 5):

In contrast to Php, Go isn’t a script run by a web server like Apache. It has another working model more close to php-fpm.

Go application is a standalone web server. It accepts connections and replies on a giver tcp port.  It’s independent of nginx which can be installed on a separate machine.
So it is supposed that app is running with external tools.

What problem do you want to solve with “launching Go app with nginx”?

**UPD**
A Complete example:

1. Install nginx on your server. Particular steps depend on your operation system. For Ubuntu it can be `apt-get install nginx`
2. Edit `nginx.conf` to add proxy pass to pot 8081:

   ```
   location / {
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/;
   }
   ```
3. Run you program `go run ...`

Comment: I understand go applicaiton is a standalone web server. What is the propper way to start/stop this application ?

Comment: Best way is to use run tool built-in into your system. This may be init scripts, systemd and so on. If you prefer Docker you may build an image then `docker start your-image`. For the start you may build a program with `go build` put Portman file into you home folder and then run `./program`